# How to get component from a JPanel using its variable name?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, cardlayout

I create a JPanel with CardLayout . With the loading of  this JPanel I add some JPanels to this JPanel . Now I want to get the first JPanel in CardLayout when loading this JPanel using its variable name . Have any ideas ?

Comment: You can't.  A component doesn't have a "variable" name, it has a memory address which variables point to. Without more context to your problem, it's difficult to know what to suggest, but, perhaps you could create a custom panel with setters and getters that allows you access to the components this component is controlling

Comment: Don't think JPanels or components. Instead think classes, objects and object-oriented principles. You would give your classes methods to allow other classes to alter their states or to extract information, and with Swing GUI's, it's exactly the same.

Comment: @MadProgrammer :- Ok . so how could I get the first JPanel in this card layout with loading of main JPanel ? If you have any idea suggest me .

Comment: Presumably you use `CardLayout#show` and pass it what ever name/identifier you game the panel when you added it - But I'm only guessing as I really don't understand your issue

Comment: If you just need the first panel you added call first().  If you need to access by variable reference, just implement your own addComponent() and store them using some Map.

Comment: Thank both of you . I solved my problem in another way.